# Lunchboxes on the master bus

Tags: mixing, mastering

Curious what combinations people have used in lunchboxes on the master bus or any summing bus for that matter and whether or not they feel it's worth the purchase over ITB. Less of a general ITB v OTB question and more about OTB in specific areas like summing. I could even use it purely for home mastering and maybe a nice pre for vocals, or just as a first step (when needed) for top-down, who knows...

A good ITB chain I found recently, courtesy of Glen over at SMG, is the SSL Comp and L3 UltraMax followed by the WLM loudness meter.

I don't feel any particular urge to buy outboard, lord knows that A v D debate has become a bit long in the tooth, but it could be fun.

Wondering if this idea evokes any useful advice from those more experienced than myself.

---

Just wanted to circle back to this as I've decided to take a different route with separating my mixing and mastering. I used to be a big fan of master bus plugins but I've made the decision to move away from that and leave the master bus to the mastering engineer. If I can't get a good mix without messing with the master bus then I need to work on my skills. That's just for me, and there is nothing inherently wrong with adding your flavour to the master bus, but hopefully it helps someone else asking themselves the same questions.

Comment: [Just so you know someone's reading this;) I can't help on this one. I've only ever worked with either minimal outboard [pre-amps only], or the full monty 48 channels of 1970s analog desk & outboard squeezed down to the compy at the last second. Nothing in between. I used to be a big fan of the ultramax, though I tend to use the L3LL these days  - & I always squeeze at least one LinMB in front of it for some more gentle shaping, sometimes on individual mic channels too. Love it for vox.

Comment: haha thanks! Yeh nice the LL3L is awesome. Always used that on mastering, pretty much every time without fail. Makes the highs so crisp and smooth, like vermouth.

Comment: Stirred, not shaken, to twist a metaphor ;))

Comment: nice, very nice..